# Running a Python file with Flask, nginx and uWSGI in Ubuntu

Tags: python, nginx, flask, ubuntu-14.04, uwsgi

For a school project, I need to run a Python API on a server. I created a droplet on Digital Ocean and installed Ubuntu. After that, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to create an environment with nginx, Flask and WSGI.

Everything works perfect, the "Hello There!" message is showing and I can change the text of it and see the change on screen. So no problems there.

The file structure at this moment is:

```
ProjectFolder
|
|── api.py (The file with "Hello There!")
|── api.ini 
|── api.sock
|── wsgi.py
|── projectenv
```

The problem is that our API code is stored in a BitBucket repository. I have cloned the repository so that the file structure becomes:

```
ProjectFolder
|
|── api.py (The file with "Hello There!")
|── api.ini 
|── api.sock
|── wsgi.py
|── projectenv/
|── bitbucketrepo/
    |── api.py
```

Of course, because of the configurations in the other files, the server still loads the api.py with the "Hello There!" text. I have changed the `wsgi.py` and the file in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` directory, so that everything directs to the api.py in the bitbucketrepo folder, but that didn't work. I also tried to move all the files in the root folder to the bitbucketrepo folder and changed the above mentioned files accordingly, but that also didn't work.

I also don't understand why the api.py with the "Hello There!" text automatically runs when I go to my server in a browser, but when I literally copy and paste my API code in that file, it doesn't work.

The code in the files are as follows:

ProjectFolder/apy.py:

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Projectfolder/api.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = api.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

ProjectFolder/wsgi.py:

```
from api import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

ProjectFolder/bitbucketrepo/api.py:

```
#imports

application = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(application)

#API code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

So my problem here is that the API in the bitbucket folder only runs when I run the command `python api.py`. When I do that, the API is accessible on port 5000. So someone can only access my API when I run that terminal command.

What I want is that the API in the bitbucket folder always runs, like the api.py in the ProjectFolder.

I have the feeling that I'm very close to achieving this, but just missing a certain step in the process. I have no experience with servers and servermanagement, so this is quite new to me.

Does anyone know which steps to take to achiev this? My apologies if there is a similar question on StackOverflow. It was not my intention to post a duplicate question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What is the error you get?

Comment: You are running the application is WSGI!... It is just simply the Flask application that it needs called `application`. Also what is `Api()` where is that class defined?

Comment: @dirn the error I get is `Internal Server Error`. Nothing more, nothing less. I also checked the error log of nginx, but it is empty. And the Python file runs perfectly when I use `python api.py`

Comment: You either need to check the uWSGI log or run your application in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
from bitbucketrepo.api import application
```

If you're using python2, make sure you have a __init__.py file in the bitbucketrepo folder.

Comment: Very stupid that I didn't think about that. But unfortunately, it's giving the same error message on screen: `Internal Server Error`. I have checked the error log of nginx but it isn't showing anything. I can also successfully run `python api.py` in the bitbucketrepo, so the code inside works.

I didn't have an init file. Just made one, so thanks for that. All the above testen was done after i created it.

Comment: Forget what I just said. I had a simple typo. Your solution worked and my API in the bitbucketrepo is finally showing on the homepage. Thank you very much!

Comment: The only thing to mention is that `init.py` didn't work (got the same Internal Server Error), but `__init__.py` did work. What is the difference between these two? One is for python2, the other for 3? Apologies for the comment spam, but I can't edit them.

Comment: @KevinKromjong I think it's a typo. He just forget to escape the _ in markdown. And I can't edit it because it's less than 6 chars.

Comment: Correct, forgot to escape __.
@KevinKromjong, the correct package identifier for Python 2 is \_\_init\_\_.py
For Python 3, there's no need for an \_\_init_\_.py file.